# Python distribution for Scientists on Linux

Tags: python, linux, distribution, pythonxy

I would like to find out if there is a Pythonxy.com equivalent for Linux/Mac OS X yet?

any kind of pointers would be helpful?

Thanks and best regards,
Vishal Sapre

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [FOSSEE](http://fossee.in) project is specifically targetted at FOSS for scientists and engineers. Their [offerings](http://fossee.in/download) are mostly Python based and might contain the tools you need.

Answer (score 5):

Pythonxy exists for linux : http://pythonxy-linux.googlecode.com

Comment: the pythonxy distribution for Linux is only an experiment as of now, there is nothing to download [on their download page](http://code.google.com/p/pythonxy-linux/downloads/list)

Comment: Yes but you can retrieve the source : hg clone https://pythonxy-linux.googlecode.com/hg/ pythonxy-linux

Answer (score 5):

For linux, you don't need something like PythonXY, because it's already very easy to install packages with your package manager. Things are actually a lot better integrated under linux than under windows.

What you need to do is pick a good linux distribution, and install the packages you like with the package manager (apt, dnf, pacman...)

Comment: It might be easy to donwload one or two packages, but the kind of packages that pythonxy comes with, is a full time project when it comes to maintainence. Managing all the different versions of packages with their conflicts etc is a full time job. We want to find if something already is present, otherwise, we'll have to do it anyways.

Comment: This is what the distribution does. Are you familiar with the concept of the package manager?

Comment: Something like: `sudo apt-get install python-numpy python-scipy python-matplotlib ipython ipython-notebook python-pandas python-sympy python-nose`

Comment: If you can't get the package manager to do it right (old version, not there, etc) you can still use pip. It works beautifully on linux, less so on Windows.

Comment: This should be the answer marked as correct. Pythonxy for Linux would be only a meta package having as dependencies numpy, pandas, etc.

Answer (score 2):

There's always [Sage](http://www.sagemath.org/).

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at the [Enthought Python Distribution](http://www.enthought.com/products/epd.php). It "provides scientists with a comprehensive set of tools to perform rigorous data analysis and visualization." EPD is available for Windows, Mac OS, RedHat, Ubuntu, Suse and Solaris. It is not free, though (and I am in no way affiliated to them).